# amsrefs package problem

Tags: bibliographies, amsrefs

I am using the `amsrefs` package with the `author-year` option. I want to delete the author's initial from the `\cite` command by using the `amsrefs` package. can anybody suggest how to achieve this?

e.g. `\cite{CR11}` --> output is Alfread A, 1997

but I want the output to be: Alfread 1997

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a wrong entry for that author, as the following example shows; upon compiling `test.tex`, which calls `nonsense.ltb` as recommended in the documentation of `amsrefs`, I get the following:

[image]

### File `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[author-year]{amsrefs} 
\begin{document} 
\ocite{Sokal96} recommends Bourbaki's 
text~\cite{Bourbaki70} for a gentle introduction to set theory. 
\begin{bibdiv} 
\begin{biblist} 
\bibselect{nonsense} 
\end{biblist} 
\end{bibdiv} 
\end{document}
```

### File `nonsense.ltb`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsrefs} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{bibdiv} 
\begin{biblist} 
\bib{Bourbaki70}{book}{ 
title={Th\'eorie des ensembles}, 
author={Bourbaki, Nicolas}, 
date={1970}, 
publisher={Hermann}, 
address={Paris} 
} 
\bib{Sokal96}{article}{ 
title={Trangressing the boundaries}, 
subtitle={Toward a transformative hermeneutics of quantum gravity}, 
author={Sokal, Alan}, 
journal={Social Text}, 
volume={46/47}, 
date={1996}, 
pages={217--252} 
} 
\bib{SokalB1998}{book}{ 
title={Fashionable Nonsense}, 
subtitle={Postmodern Intellectuals' Abuse of Science}, 
author={Sokal, Alan}, 
author={Bricmont, Jean}, 
publisher={Picador USA}, 
address={New York}, 
date={1998} 
} 
\end{biblist} 
\end{bibdiv} 
\end{document}
```

### What can be wrong?

I get "Sokal Alan (1996)" in the first citation if the author field is

```
author={Sokal Alan},
```

without the comma.